# embedded video, change black background to custom image or first video scene

Tags: javascript, html, video

I embedded video on my webpage. Everything works but I want to change those black start image to some custom image, or first scene (just to remove black background). Video is uploaded to website server, so it's not embedded at youtube or any other video provider.

update:
I tried with property [previewImage](http://labs.divx.com/book/export/html/16584) but nothing changes. I added to the code below

```
<param name="previewImage" value="/Content/uploads/video/video_preview.jpg">
```

but background remains black.

here's the code I'm using

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" 
        width="235" height="180" id="http://www.mysite.com/Content/uploads/video/player_flv_maxi.swf" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.mysite.com/Content/uploads/video/player_flv_maxi.swf?flv=http://www.mysite.com/Content/uploads/video/my_video.flv">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    <embed src="http://www.mysite.com/Content/uploads/video/player_flv_maxi.swf?flv=http://www.mysite.com/Content/uploads/video/my_video.flv" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="235" height="180" name="http://www.mysite.com/Content/uploads/video/player_flv_maxi.swf" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
```

Comment: This is a proprietary question for whatever player_flv_maxi.swf is.  I really recommend shifting to HTML5 video.  I personally removed Flash from my computer years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code instead

```
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flv-player.net/medias/player_flv.swf">
      <param name="movie" value="http://flv-player.net/medias/player_flv.swf" />
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
      <param name="FlashVars" value="flv=http%3A//www.YOURVIDEO.flv&amp;startimage=YOUR_VIDEO_PREVIEW_IMAGE.jpg&amp; />
 </object>
```

You can explore and add more properties to your video using flv player online generator
http://flv-player.net/players/normal/generator/

But I would strongly suggest to switch to html5.